# Error in Webservice.invoke : Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element result

Tags: apex, integration, soap, wsdl

world!

I'm trying to call via SOAP to a function called *putRecogida*.

When I execute it via SoapUI, it works perfectly, but when I loaded both classes into salesforce with apex2wsdl tool, both APEX classes generates an error:

> Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element result

when I try to use it.

The snippets are:

**NacexSoapAPI.cls**

```
public class NacexSoapAPI {
public class putRecogida {
    public String String_1;
    public String String_2;
    public String[] arrayOfString_3;
    private String[] String_1_type_info = new String[]{'String_1','urn:soap/types',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] String_2_type_info = new String[]{'String_2','urn:soap/types',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] arrayOfString_3_type_info = new String[]{'arrayOfString_3','urn:soap/types',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:soap/types','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'String_1','String_2','arrayOfString_3'};
}
public class putRecogidaResponse {
    String[] return_x;
    private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','urn:soap/types',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:soap/types','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
}
public class nacexwsImplPort {
    public String endpoint_x = 'https://pda.nacex.com/nacex_ws/soap';
    public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
    public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public String clientCert_x;
    public String clientCertPasswd_x;
    public Integer timeout_x;
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array', 'NacexJaxbDevArray', 'urn:soap/types', 'NacexSoapAPI'};

    public String[] putRecogida(String String_1,String String_2,String[] arrayOfString_3) {
        NacexSoapAPI.putRecogida request_x = new NacexSoapAPI.putRecogida();
        request_x.String_1 = String_1;
        request_x.String_2 = String_2;
        request_x.arrayOfString_3 = arrayOfString_3;
        NacexSoapAPI.putRecogidaResponse response_x;
        Map<String, NacexSoapAPI.putRecogidaResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, NacexSoapAPI.putRecogidaResponse>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[]{endpoint_x, // Endpoint
            '', // SOAP action
            'urn:soap/types', // request namespace
            'putRecogida', // request name
            'urn:soap/types', // response namespace
            'putRecogidaResponse', //  response name
            'NacexSoapAPI.putRecogidaResponse'} // response type
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');

        return response_x.return_x;
    }
}
}
```

**NacexJaxbDevArray.cls**

```
public class NacexJaxbDevArray {
        public class stringArray {
            public String[] item;
            private String[] item_type_info = new String[]{'item','http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array',null,'0','-1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array','false','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'item'};
        }
    }
```

You can find the WSDL I loaded into Salesforce [here](http://pda.nacex.com/nacex_ws/soap?wsdl), but I think the relevant piece is *putrecogida*:
[image: WSDL Snap]

Can anyone PLEASE tell me how can I work around it so I can get the response properly?

Thanks a lot in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end,
based on [this previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331432/web-service-callout-failed-unable-to-parse-callout-response-apex-type-not-foun?rq=1), I've decided to read [Daniel's post](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/03/an-alternative-to-salesforces-wsdl2apex.html), where he recommends [FuseIt SFDC Explorer](https://www.fuseit.com/contact/downloads/). I've tried to upload my WSDL there, and it has generated a proper class that makes everything work!

Highly recommended!